# CSS Enquiry (Margins? Padding?)

Tags: html, css

[image: Please see screenshot here]

I would like the li elements to be stuck to the header-container border element as opposed to the top of the page.

Basically, removing the white gap between the li element and the header-container border, then leaving the gap with the top of the page instead.

I've tried with margins, increasing padding... does not work.

Please see CSS for screenshot attached below:

```
nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 17px;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;

    color: #000000;
    background: #f3f2f2;
}
```

HTML code as requested:

```
<div class="header-container">
            <header class="wrapper clearfix">
                <h1 class="title"><img src="img/mimosa.png" alt="logo"></h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="lodging.html">Lodging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tinfo.html">Tourist Info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your html code as well. only css won't help us.

Comment: you can always try using divs

Comment: you haven't showed us enough code to help you. have you tried removing margin and padding from both `ul` and `li` ?

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eY9px/)

Comment: @LokeshSuthar, let me know if this and the posted below suffices, it's a bit frustating for me as I don't know how to put all the elements you need at your reach. Will sincerely appreciate your guidance as I'm new in here.

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this but I think the best way would be to rectify your code. But as you can see the fiddle you provided is not at all close to what we see in the image. So it would be great if you could provide a test site or recitfy the fiddle

Comment: @LokeshSuthar, fiddle now updated. If the logo being used is of a certain height, it creates the gap seen on the screenshot, I would like that gap with the top of the page as opposed than with the border of the header-container. I can provide more info if required, thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the fiddle, that helped
ok, the issue is caused by your image being on the same horizontal area as the nav 
the image size pushed the links up. 
a quick way to solve this is to add this

```
.title{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:40px;
}
```

just adjust the top and left as you need them.
and double check with the mobile settings. you may need to position it differently if min-width is however many you set mobile to

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately I tried with those settings and the links keep being pushed up.

Comment: I'm about to give up with this site, this is killing my reputation, which directly affects the elements I can provide for other people to help me, now it is at 4 and I cannot even publish links... This is driving me insane, I don't understand what the site is doing and I don't know where to ask for help, sincerely.

Comment: what else can I share with you? I would like the gap between the links and the header removed, I want those 2 to stick together. What I'd like is a gap between the links and the very top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to make them into divs and then seperate them as needed. like this

```
ul > li /* design the look and feel */
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px; /* specify the spacing between each list item. */
 }
li /* stretch each list item */
{
    width:170px;
}
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZfLG/)

Answer (score 0):

is the whole tab a link or only the text?
you have a padding 15px on the link. so if you are using an image for the tab you could try to change that to :

```
padding-top: 15px;
```

alternately you could try :

```
nav li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe the [following screenshot](http://min.us/i/UIgvf5NnnuUK) will help you better.

Comment: I tried your fix and it did not work, do you need more bits of code? This is probably a question that would be more typical of a novice, it's as frustrating for me because I don't know how to put all the elements you need at reach. I would like to remove the gap between the li/ul element and the header-container border, essentially switching that gap so it is on the top on the page. I don't know which of the CSS/HTML is leading the ul/li elements to stuck to the very top of the page.

Comment: can you post your complete css for the Nav and Header divs?

Comment: If the logo being used is of a certain height, it creates the gap seen on the screenshot, I would like that gap with the top of the page as opposed than with the border of the header-container.

Answer (score 0):

What I got is sometimes if 0 padding or margin doesn't work then u can use negative padding or margins, u can try that!

Answer (score 0):

change your li tags style into

```
nav ul li
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

this is the : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZfLG/) :)

Comment: [This is what the fiddle does](http://min.us/i/boGljckqdB055) looks odd... Any turnarounds?

Comment: Floating elements create more trouble than good for most beginner developers as they don't fully understand the implications. This isn't a good answer.